# tensorflow reduce_mean with multidimension second argument

Tags: tensorflow

I met the usage of the reduce_mean with the vector as the second arguments. I looked through sensor flow manual but can't find the corresponding example. The codes are below:

```
tf.reduce_mean(train, [0,1,2]
```

where train is at size batchsize x H x L x 2
I also played with some experiments but can't figure out how this second vector input will be processed

```
tensor = tf.constant([[[2,2,4],[2,2,0]],[[2,2,0],[2,2,0]]])
trainenergy = tf.reduce_mean(tensor, [0,1,2])
Output = 1
tensor = tf.constant([[[2,2,4],[2,2,0]],[[2,2,0],[2,2,0]]])
trainenergy = tf.reduce_mean(tensor, [0])
Output = [[2 2 2]
 [2 2 0]]
tensor = tf.constant([[[2,2,4],[2,2,0]],[[2,2,0],[2,2,0]]])
trainenergy = tf.reduce_mean(tensor, [0,1])
Output = [2 2 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just figure out tf.reduce_mean(train, [0,1,2]) if the second argument is the vector. It will reduce the dimension as the order of the element is the vector. For example, the [0,1,2] will reduce along the axis of 0,1,2